# Asp.Net MVC 4.5 Repository Update Method, referential integrity constraint violation occured

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application. I'm using the Repository Pattern in my BLL. I'm trying to implement the Update method and map updatedOffer(vm) to my originalOffer(poco).

To respect DRY and not duplicate the code in Create and Update, I use the method OfferVmToOffer to generate a new poco from my viewmodel.

Anyways, I'm getting this error when I try to "update" the originalOffer:

**A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) on the other end**

```
public void UpdateOffer(OfferVm updatedOffer)
{
    var originalOffer = Db.Offer.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OfferId == updatedOffer.OfferId);

    if(originalOffer != null)
    {
        var tmpOffer = OfferVmToOffer(updatedOffer);

        tmpOffer.ActorPoolId = originalOffer.ActorPoolId;
        tmpOffer.SkillPoolId = originalOffer.SkillPoolId;
        tmpOffer.SwotPoolId = originalOffer.SwotPoolId;
        tmpOffer.TargetPoolId = originalOffer.TargetPoolId;
        tmpOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPoolId = originalOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPoolId;

        originalOffer = tmpOffer;

        // mark as modified => here i'm getting the error
        Db.Entry(originalOffer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }            
}
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change 'tmpOffer.ActorPoolId = originalOffer.ActorPoolId;' to 'originalOffer.ActorPoolId = tmpOffer.ActorPoolId;' in all sentences, and then remove the 'originalOffer = tmpOffer;'?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of difficult to answer without seeing `Offer` model, `OfferVm` and `OfferVmToOffer` view models, but what about updating your code to the following?

```
public void UpdateOffer(OfferVm updatedOffer)
{
    var originalOffer = Db.Offer.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OfferId == updatedOffer.OfferId);

    if(originalOffer != null)
    {
        originalOffer.ActorPoolId = updatedOffer.ActorPoolId;
        originalOffer.SkillPoolId = updatedOffer.SkillPoolId;
        originalOffer.SwotPoolId = updatedOffer.SwotPoolId;
        originalOffer.TargetPoolId = updatedOffer.TargetPoolId;
        originalOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPoolId = updatedOffer.OfferData.DeliveryModelPoolId;

        Db.Entry(originalOffer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }            
}
```